# How do I get the ASP.NET ForgotPassword tool to use Postmark?

Tags: c#, asp.net

All my app's mail is currently sent through Postmark, except for the basic ASP.NET membership controls.

Any ideas on how to get the emails generated from those controls to pass onward to my Postmark  acct?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use Postmark for ASP.NET Login controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468182/how-can-i-use-postmark-for-asp-net-login-controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468182/how-can-i-use-postmark-for-asp-net-login-controls) is of any help.