# How can I use Postmark for ASP.NET Login controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm wondering how I can use Postmark for sending emails rather than specifying an SMTP in the web.config for the various login controls:

asp:RecoverPassword
asp:ChangePassword

I don't want to use SMTP, Postmark is doing a great job with all of our other email.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can implement the control's `OnSendingMail` event which receives a `MailMessageEventArgs` containing the message it was about to send. You should be able to then send the mail yourself and set `Cancel` in the event args which - at first glance - won't interfere with the rest of the password reset workflow.